# Springboot default data.sql not loading on startup

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I've got this `Spring Boot` application that is working with a `PostgreSQL` database. The `application-dev.properties` file is as follows:

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root


spring.datasource.data=classpath:/sql/dev-data.sql


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=myschema

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
```

The database is installed in my development machine, and already initialized. The `dev-data.sql` file is in `src/main/resources/sql` and right now only deletes everything on a specific table (lets call it `myschema.example_table`) and inserts some registries. (This is intended to check the functionality works than for an actual use):

```
delete from myschema.example_table where id > 0;

insert into myschema.example_table (id, val1, val2) values (1, "Hello", "Petecander");
insert into myschema.example_table (id, val1, val2) values (2, "Goodbye", "Gromenauer");
```

My issue is that... nothing happens. Is as if there wasn't anything related to the `dev-data.sql` file at all. So, I'm completely at a loss here. I've been browsing for a while, and reading about a lot of different switches that can be enabled on the `application.properties` file, but nothing. Any idea?

**EDIT**: Just to provide a bit more of info that I've been asked down there: The application loads fine and can perform some basic CRUD stuff against the database (Just read stuff at the moment), so the `application-dev.properties` file seems that is being loaded right.

Comment: Why you named it as `dev-data.sql`? Why not `data.sql`?

Comment: I don't think `spring.datasource.platform=postgres` is necessary since spring will determine the db from the URL where possible. Presumably if you're running this against localhost you've mapped the port from a docker container? Is `5432` the right port? You've specified DB as `postgres` but schema as `myschema` for hibernate - could this be an issue? Presumably when you're spring boot app it sets the profile to `dev` so that `application-dev.properties` is the property source in use? I can think of ways to test but there's questions that need answering before you can have a plan to debug this

Comment: Answering @RobEvans: The application runs the basic CRUD operations "just fine" and the database is not in a docker container, but installed in my dev machine (We are in really early stages of development, the idea is going with docker, just not yet). And yeah, the application-dev.properties file is being load (it has all the connection info to the database, so either that or magic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate will **only** execute `data.sql` for either `create` or `create-drop`

Add any of the following property to your `application properties` file:

- `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`
- `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`

This is required along with the property
`spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always` for external (not embedded) databases.

Comment: Yeah, that did it! I used `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`, as the database is created and "stable" at the moment (Although my idea for the future is to use a ddl on develop to create the database). Had to fix some minor problems with my SQL and now is working. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is useful, but the _"Hibernate will **only** execute `data.sql` for either `create` or `create-drop`"_ sentence seems confuse against [spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like some of the suggestions are deprecated now.

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Needs to be replaced with:

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

Here is a picture of my application.properties settings for a local H2 database if this helps anybody:
[Spring H2 Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHJB1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to name file **data.sql**? I think it could help https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar issue and found my answer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc). If you add:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

To your properties it should work.

Comment: Didn't work. It was one of the "lot of different switches" I mentioned on my original post (I've tried already a lot of combinations to no avail).

Comment: are you sure the properties are being loaded?

Comment: Yeah, the application.properties file only has `spring.profiles.active=dev`, application-dev.properties has all the connection data for the local database (and I can perform basic CRUD operations) and the console is telling me that is running with the "dev" profile.

Answer (score 0):

For embedded database like h2 , adding below entries in application.properties worked for me.

> spring.datasource.data=classpath:mysql.sql

Answer (score 0):

For spring boot version 2.7, adding `spring.sql.init.mode=always` to application properties will work.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many things, and in the end i found that the combination of

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

and

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

did the trick for me.